# Optimizing Aggregate for Whole Object Query MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization, aggregation-framework

I have the following aggregation pipeline that is taking around 5 **seconds**(!!) to complete.

I tried using indexes on the client_id and list fields, but it still varies from 430ms to 4217ms to complete. Also, if I fire more than 30 concurrent requests, it starts to generate some erros and lock.

How would be the best way to optimize it?

```
Schema.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $match: { $or: [
         { list: null, owner: new ObjectId(req.user.id) },
         { list: { $in:  lists.map(function(id){ return new ObjectId(id); }) } }
       ],
       client_id: req.user.active_client_id
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {_id: { parent: "$parent" }, subjobs: { $push: '$$ROOT'}, count:{ $sum: 1}}
    },
    {
     $project: { _id: "$_id.parent", subjobs: 1  }
    }
  ]
)
```

It is running against a database with the following config:

1GB **SSD** 
Documents on the collection: **6K**
Data Size: **10.6MB**

Sample Document:

```
  {
    _id: ObjectId("554be66d17da350e00e1dde0"),
    last_update: ISODate("2015-10-13T13:49:06.961Z"),
    title: "SAMPLE DATA",
    owner: null,
    list: ObjectId("556dca89a5447c0e000afdfe"),
    events: [ARRAY OF OBJECTS],
    chat: [ARRAY OF OBJECTS],
    tags: [ARRAY OF OBJECTS],
    date_created: ISODate("2015-05-07T22:25:49.629Z"),
    completed: false,
    state: "canceled",
    phase: "void",
    __v: 9,
    up_week: false,
    client_id: "554bd0068fe",
    delegation_accepted: false,
    labels: [ARRAY OF OBJECTS],
    was_delegated: false
  }
```

Comment: Are you creating 2 indexes (1 for client_id and another for list) or 1 multiple fields index that has both client_id and list (db.collection.createIndex( { client_id: 1, list: 1 } )?  You probably need to use multiple fields index.

Comment: I first created one for each, but then I created one for both, like you said  { client_id: 1, list: 1 }, but there was no big improvement. Would it be necessary to drop the others?

Comment: Actually, just noticed the $or there.  You need to create 2 compound indexes. 1) {list:1, client_id:1}, 2) {list: 1, owner: 1, client_id: 1}.  It's a large set of data.  You might need to wait for a while for the creation of indexes to complete to see the result.

Comment: Ok! I will try that and check if it will improve. I am now trying to change the $group and $project part to be done using nodejs instead of mongo.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if moving $group/$project to nodejs will improve the time.  It might actually be the opposite because mongodb is implemented in compiled language (c/c++) while javascript is interpreted language.  One thing to improve the performance is to add another $project before $group since this reduces the amount of memory it needs for this operation.

Comment: One more thing, $group is doing the count but $project after that is not interested in that count.  Reduce the count in $group will save you some time there.  That count is actually subjobs.length, so you already have the count without counting in $group.

Comment: The NodeJS approach, was indeed quite a bump. It was relative fast, but the memory use increased way more than I would have expected. The two compound indexes approach improved a lot for a **single query**, but it stills quite slow with multiple queries being fired. Later today I will try those other modifications. The $count is indeed not used anywhere else and if needed the .length will do the trick. Great observation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to model my schema as the result of the aggregation pipeline and change the parts of the system to use the relation as in the $group.

Current times are around 200-430ms for that same amount.